# How to format text using shiny html?

Tags: html, r, shiny, shinybs

In the example code at the bottom, I'm trying to format the text rendered inside the shinyBS package `popify()` function as shown in the image below (reduce bullet indentation and right justify the text). I believe this code uses shiny html. How could this be done?

[image]

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

app = shinyApp(
  ui =
    fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(sliderInput("bins","Number of bins:",min = 1,max = 50,value = 30)),
        mainPanel(
          plotOutput("distPlot"),
          uiOutput("uiExample"))
      )
    ),
  server =
    function(input, output, session) {
      output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        x <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
      })
      output$uiExample <- renderUI({
        tagList(
          tags$span("Little circle >>"),
          tags$span(
            popify(icon("info-circle", verify_fa = FALSE),
                   "Placeholder",
                   paste(
                   "This table below presents a whole bunch of great information so strap in:",
                   "<ul>",
                   "<li>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</li>",
                   "<li>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</li>",
                   "<li>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</li>",
                   "<li>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</li>",
                   "<li>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah",
                    "Blah blah blah blah blah blah.</li>",
                   "</ul>")
            )
          )  
        )
      })
    }
)

runApp(app)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your UI

```r
            tags$style(
                '
                .popover ul {padding: 1px; text-align: right;}
                '
            )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

And incorporating Iz100's answer into the complete code with my desired formatting:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

app = shinyApp(
  ui =
    fluidPage(
      tags$style('.popover ul {padding: 15px; text-align: justify;}'), # << Iz100 solution here
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(sliderInput("bins","Number of bins:",min = 1,max = 50,value = 30)),
        mainPanel(
          plotOutput("distPlot"),
          uiOutput("uiExample"))
      )
    ),
  server =
    function(input, output, session) {
      output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        x <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
      })
      output$uiExample <- renderUI({
        tagList(
          tags$span("Little circle >>"),
          tags$span(
            popify(icon("info-circle", verify_fa = FALSE),
                   "Placeholder",
                   paste(
                   "This table below presents a whole bunch of great information so strap in:",
                   "<ul>",
                   "<li>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</li>",
                   "<li>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</li>",
                   "<li>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</li>",
                   "<li>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</li>",
                   "<li>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah",
                    "Blah blah blah blah blah blah.</li>",
                   "</ul>")
            )
          )  
        )
      })
    }
)

runApp(app)
```